# Lucene 2.4.1 indices to be reindexed with lucene 6.2.1

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I am new to lucene and trying to reindex lucene 2.4.1 indices to lucene 6.2.1 indices.

I came across various forums and got to know that it is feasible through `IndexUpgrader` utility in lucene but the concern here is - I can't directly convert lucene 2.4.1 indices to lucene 6.2.1 indices.

I need to upgrade the indices to lucene 3.x.x and the to lucene 4.x.x and so on.

Curious to know if there are any alternatives.

Requesting you all to kindly help me on this.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, something other than `IndexUpgrader` wouldn't be that reliable unless certified by few developers.

I am not aware of any other tool but what you can do is - Write a script for your target environment ( shell/bash/batch etc ) which uses this tool to upgrade your index in one go instead of you firing multiple commands manually if that is too much of a task or if manual command is not an option.

You can write your own Java class/utility too to upgrade in one go since you can fire java commands from a class using `ProcessBuilder` or something like that or probably you can invoke `upgrade()` method on various `IndexUpgraders.

Here is a sample bash script that you can test and tweak for your requirement - [upgradeindex.sh](https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex)

All in all you will have to write a wrapper on top of this tool to automate the process for your own need.

Reference - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexUpgrader+Tool

Comment: Thanks for replying Sabir, one more question on the same lucene upgrade scenario :
How to validate the correctness of the re-indexed data? How do I ensure if all the indices have been correctly converted from lucene 2.4.1 to lucene 6.2.1, also which lucene jars I need to include for re-indexing? there are multiple version of jars for lucene 3.x, lucene 4.x and so on.

Comment: I am not very sure about validation part and as a precaution you should always have a back up. Probably, you can  use checkIndex() method of  [this CheckIndex class](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html)

Comment: I guess, since you are firing upgrade command one by one sequentially, you will need core and backward-codec jars for all those versions that you are upgrading for.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response @Sabir Khan, taking the backup would not be feasible as the data is huge(may be 200-300 GB).

I could not find lucene 3.x and lucene 4.x codecs jars, moreover when I convert lucene indices from 2.x to 3.x and then to 4.x no codecs jars were needed, but when i tried converting lucene 4.x indices to lucene 5.x it complained for lucene42 codec jar. Please see the below error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not load codec 'Lucene42'.  Did you forget to add lucene-backward-codecs.jar?

Comment: which version of 5.x?

Comment: its lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.3.jar and lucene-core-5.5.3.jar
The command is  : java -cp /root/lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.3.jar:/root/lucene-core-5.5.3.jar org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader -delete-prior-commits -verbose [ path to indexed data ]

Comment: `lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.3.jar` has lucene42 codecs included. Not sure whats going on.META-INF\services on that jar has codec entry too.Looks to be some kind of jar packaging issue with the jar that you have.

Comment: From the lucene documentation I learned that lucene-core-5.5.3.jar is the last major stable version available. Any suggestion here? should I use any other 5.x.x jar? Also the same issue persist (backward-codec jars are expected in conversion)when I re-index to lucene 6.2.1 [i.e converting lucene 5.3.3 indices to lucene 6.2.1 indices]